# Is there a way to detect if a PiTFT display screen is connected?

Tags: gpio, display, pitft

I am trying to detect if a [PiTFT screen](http://www.adafruit.com/product/1601) is connected.

Is there some kind of GPIO pin I can probe and detect it to some extent?

Comment: Other than printing message and asking the operator to press a button if he could read it ;) But I'd assume that the controller attached to the Pi by a serial interface has to report in somehow. After all there is a touchpanel and those values have to be sent to the Pi? The documentation at the given link is however quite scarce.

Comment: @Ghanima You can't just print a message, because setup requires in some cases to re-flash the firmware of the pi. I am building a distro and I want it to support multiple screens

Comment: Sure, the first part of that comment was a little less serios. My question being that a display-touchpanel combination got to have a bi-directional interface. Thus the Pi should be able to send something and get some response... or at least that was what I hoped.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, answering for someone else who might need it... Full disclaimer - this is what I collected in the last couple of days researching a different topic - there are might be better ways. That said, it seems there are at least a few possibilities for detecting a TFT screen. For one, you can query the device tree as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/how-to-detect-what-kind-of-hat-or-gpio-board-is-plugged-in-if-any):

```
$ cat /proc/device-tree/hat/product
PiTFT 2.2inch without Touchscreen (ILI9340)
```

You can also see if the backlight device is registered (found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder)):

```
$ sudo find /sys/ -type f -iname '*brightness*' | grep 'led'
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:leds/leds/led0/brightness
/sys/devices/platform/soc/soc:leds/leds/led0/max_brightness
```

Or read the status of the backlight [led](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi/backlight-control) directly (will be 0 if off):

```
 $ gpio  read 18
1
```

You can also check if there is more than one framebuffer (TFT runs on fb1 unless you have more than one monitor):

```
$ ls /sys/class/graphics/
fb0  fb1  fbcon
```

You can probably also talk directly to the TFT controller, but the options above seem simpler.