# How raspberry pi talk with its HAT's

Tags: explorer-hat

I got bit confusion about the new raspberry pi HAT. Lets say we have a configured HAT with a right EEPROM, when the pi starts how it talks to the HAT ? What tool does it use (is it SMbus ? )? and how it prepare the HAT to be usable ?

Answer (score 5):

> In a nutshell a HAT is a rectangular board (65x56mm) that has four
>   mounting holes in the (nicely rounded) corners that align with the
>   mounting holes on the B+, has a 40W GPIO header and supports the
>   special autoconfiguration system that allows automatic GPIO setup and
>   driver setup. The automatic configuration is achieved using 2
>   dedicated pins (ID_SD and ID_SC) on the 40W B+ GPIO header that are
>   reserved for an I2C EEPROM. **The EEPROM holds the board manufacturer
>   information, GPIO setup and a thing called a ‘device tree‘ fragment –
>   basically a description of the attached hardware that allows Linux to
>   automatically load the required drivers**

My bold.

See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/introducing-raspberry-pi-hats/

So the HAT is queried via I2C on GPIO 0/1 (pins 27/28 on the expansion header) and has the needed device tree information to set up the GPIO.  This is all handled by the kernel during boot.

Comment: Hmm, are these "hats" stackable or one at a time?

Comment: One at a time.  I understand that stackable HATs added too many design problems.  You may be able to stack identical HATs.

Comment: One hat at a time. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/39153/19949