# How to detect list of available sensors and actuators reside on a HAT?

Tags: raspbian, sensor, hat, sense-hat

I have been working with many *HATs* along with **Raspberry Pi** such as *Sense HAT*, *Pimoroni Enviro pHAT*; and so on. However, HATs report its existence to the device tree in `/proc/device-tree/hat` and `/sys/firmware/devicetree/base/hat` (see details from [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/how-to-detect-what-kind-of-hat-or-gpio-board-is-plugged-in-if-any)). I could extract few information (such as ***product***, ***vendor***; and so on) that were answered in that Q/A. I could enlist the list of ***sensors*** (i.e ***temperature***, ***pressure***, ***humidity***; and so on) available on a HAT from vendor/manufacturer end (through website/guidelines) manually. The complexity increases as the number of HATs increases. Anyway, is it possible to read these information (list of available sensors on a HAT) either from ***PROM / EPROM / EEPROM***?

Comment: *"It would be very easy if there is an automated way."* This made me laugh :)

Comment: My point is not that actually for what you have been laughing. The point was that `How many sensors a HAT has on it and what are those?` and `Could we enlist those sensors by reading the PROM / EPROM / EEPROM or DEVICE-TREE or manufacturer's API once the HAT (SenseHAT, or pHAT or whatever) determined?`

Comment: Yes, sorry - my humor was inappropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in [HAT requirements](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats#hat-requirements) about supplying a machine-readable list of sensors. Therefore, there is no generic methods to list sensors on a HAT: even if such a method exists, it will be manufacturer-specific at best and HAT-unique at worst.

HAT EEPROM [contains](https://github.com/raspberrypi/hats/blob/master/devicetree-guide.md) either a device tree overlay or a name of such overlay in an external file. See if parsing that gives you the information you need (though it's far from a "list of sensors").

Comment: In addition: There are Hats that don't even have an EEPROM module on them.

Comment: @PMF Those are add-on boards, not HATs.

Comment: Are you suggesting to make an API to enlist the available sensors? For example, Sense HAT has six different sensors: 1) Temperature, 2) Humidity, 3) Pressure, 4) Accelerometer, 5) Magnetometer; and 6) Gyroscope.